# How to save a new MySQL database into a different storage location?

Tags: mysql, windows

I'm using WAMP and I want to save a new database into a different HDD because I don't have enough free space in the current one.
How can I do that?

NOTE: I don't need WAMP, it's OK if I can run MYSQL alone, and I don't need the databases from the other HDD, I just need a way to save a new database in a different HDD, any recommendation is welcome :)

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do it for just a single database, but you can definitely move all of them over.

Comment: please @ceejayoz remove the duplicate, is not the same and I have found a very easy solution that could be useful for someone else

Comment: Your easy solution was listed in the duplicate. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ceejayoz I didn't see it, the solutions were for Linux and also I was searching the error and didn't find anything. Anyway you can now mark it as duplicate again

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are more elegant solutions but this easy trick works fine for me:

1) Edit: "c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\my.ini" and change the "datadir" option, something like:

```
;datadir="c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/data"    
datadir="YOUR NEW DATA FOLDER PATH"
```

2) Copy the original "data" into your new path (without this I was getting errors like "wampmysqld64: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist"

3) Start Wamp

Comment: Yes, changing `datadir` is how to do it.